# Whats the best way to combine two data frames one over the other without losing the headers?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Suppose I have two data frames that have the same column numbers, like so:

```
table    number    one
1        a         NA
2        b         NA
3        c         NA

table    number    two
4        x         NA
5        y         NA
6        z         NA
```

Whats the best way to combine these two data frames such that the headers for the two tables are not lost? Which means combining these two such that the first row remains the header (that is obvious) and the header for the second table remains a header just below the last row of the first table.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There isn't really a way to do exactly what you describe without converting every single column to characters or factors.

Comment: What you want to do makes no sense, you want your header to be a row in the data of your table.  Maybe you can describe your reasons for wanting this so that we can find the sense.

Comment: As a matter of what you see on the screen, you could put the data.frames into a list, like `list(df1,df2)`. This will likely also be convenient for other operations.

Comment: The best way to do what you want would be to not do it.

Comment: `library(data.table) #1.9.5+; rbindlist(list(df1,df2),fill=T,use.names=T)` is probably the better way to to what you have in mind

Comment: @Kasterna It does make sense. I want the two data tables combined one over the other with both their headers intact. Its like using Excel with the headers highlighted to indicate there are two tables combined. Its part of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
rbind(df1, names(df2), setNames(df2, names(df1)))
```

Output:

```
  table number  one
1     1      a <NA>
2     2      b <NA>
3     3      c <NA>
4 table number  two
5     4      x <NA>
6     5      y <NA>
7     6      z <NA>
```

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text ="table    number    one
                              1        a         NA
                              2        b         NA
                              3        c         NA",  
                      header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- read.table(text ="table    number    two
                              4        x         NA
                              5        y         NA
                              6        z         NA", 
                      header =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi @Shivendra Sharma if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.